# JButtons not appearing

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to write a simple program for now but the actual JButton is not appearing for some reason, here is my code below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Shoes");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setSize(400,500);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JButton welcome = new JButton("Click here");
        welcome.setLocation(100,100);
        welcome.setVisible(true);
            // doesn't work, but is there another way to make it so?
    //add(welcome);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not adding the button to the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the button, but did not add it.

You have to add it to the `window`. Simply using `add(welcome)` will add it to your frame, which you extend, but not to the `window` in which you want it to show.

Instead of:

```
add(welcome);
```

Just do:

```
window.add(welcome);
```

Comment: I would also mention that if you are instantiating a jframe, you don't need to extend it. (Which would make this code less confusing), and make errors like his commented out code not compile

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to mention that the reason the code on your commented out section didnt work, is because you're extending JFrame.

When you extend JFrame, you inherit all of the methods JFrame has. That includes `add()`. However, when you use `this.add()` you are adding the compononent to you Test Object (which is also a JFrame), not your `window` JFrame.

To add to the window you would use `window.add(welcome);`

To stop these weird confusions in the future I would also change
`public class Test extends JFrame`
to
`public class Test`

Answer (score 0):

you extended `JFrame` yet in your code you use another `JFrame` that you created `JFrame window = new JFrame("Shoes");`, this is why `add(welcome);` is not working for you... since its trying to add the `JButton` to `this` instance of your `Test` `class`(which is not visible) and not the `window` you have created.

You have 2 ways of solving this:

The first one as mentioned by @Hackerdarshi is to add the button to the `window` you created. like :  `window.add(welcome);`

The second way is to make use of your extension of the `JFrame` `class`(otherwhise why extend at all) and call all the methods on the `window` using `this` instance of your `Test` `class`:

```
public Test() {
    super("Shoes");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(400,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JButton welcome = new JButton("Click here");
    welcome.setLocation(100,100);
    welcome.setVisible(true);
        // this will work since `this` instance is set to visible
    add(welcome);
}
```

NOTE that to set the buttons location like: `welcome.setLocation(100,100);` you should use a `null` `Layout`